# Liferay ServiceBuilder doesn't alter tables

Tags: sql, maven, liferay, alter

### Short story

When I modify the column withs in tables.sql (VARCHAR(4000)) generated by the service builder, redeploying the portlet does not cause Liferay to alter the db tables. How can I make sure that the column withs get expanded?

### Long story

I have to make some changes to a Liferay 6.1.20 EE GA2 project developed by another contractor. The project uses maven as a build tool.

After adding some columns to the `service.xml` and running `mvn liferay:build-service`, I noticed, that the `portlet-model-hints.xml`got overriden (see https://issues.liferay.com/browse/MAVEN-37) and resettet to the default column width.

There's alot of data in the tables (it is running in production mode), so I cannot simply drop and recreate the tables.

So I manually modified the column width in the generated `tables.sql` and redeployed the portlet. The new columns are now present in the db tables, but the column widths were not altered.

Does Liferay alter column width or do I have to fire some sql statements against the database manually?

(We are working with an oracle 10g database)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the column withs, you need to write in the portlet-model-hints.xml.
For instance, to increase a field until 255 you will do:(Its important running the build service after that change.)

[image]

Comment: I've tried that. But due to the Maven-37 issue I mentioned in my question, the model-hints gets overriden. That's why I've tried to modiy the generated tables.sql manually.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceBuilder doesn't do `ALTER TABLE` by itself - you'll have to write an UpgradeProcess for this yourself. Check [this blog post](https://www.liferay.com/web/roberto.diaz/blog/-/blogs/create-an-upgrade-process-in-6-2) or the underlying documentation.

In short: The update that can always be done automatically is of the type "DROP TABLE - CREATE TABLE", but, as you say, this is typically not desirable. Any more fancy way needs to be done manually, and that's exactly what this mechanism is for.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The strange thing is: I just created a dummy portlet with an entity called Foo and a column of type string. After deployment, I added some data to it, added some model-hints to change it's size to 24, rerun the service builder **using ant** and redeployed it. I got no log messages regarding the tables during deployment, but the coumn width is now 24. So somehow the service builder did alter the table!?!

Comment: That's news to me. Does it still contain all the data it had before? Or did it actually DROP TABLE; CREATE TABLE?

Comment: The data is still present. Steps to reproduce: 1st) Create new portlet with dummy entity. 2nd) Deploy portlet. 3rd) Check column size is 75 (I use SQuirreL SQL). 4th) Modify model-hints as suggested by Fernando. 5th) rerun ant service builder. 5th) redeploy. 6) check solumn sizes again

Comment: AFAIK the complete cycle performed is data backup, drop, create, restore data: so it's possible that you find the same data after the table has been dropped and re-created during startup. I used ANT and any modification will result in this behavior; you can notice this better with BIG tables, since the startup takes next to forever. I have to check if the data restore is done row-by-row or some sort of bulk.